# How to I stop someone from finding a username and password in a PHP file?

Tags: php

I have a PHP file that uses digest authentication to call another device.  Unfortunately, I need to put the username and password in the PHP file to make it work.  I'm guessing this is not safe, and I'd like to know how I could make this more secure.

```
<?php  
function getdata($url, $username, $password) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $results = curl_exec($ch);    
    curl_close($ch);
    return $results;
    }

$livedata = getdata("http://examplesite.com?options","User","SecretPassword");
?>
```

Comment: What do you want it to be safe from? Nobody should be able to access your PHP source code directly.

Comment: You could add a login form from which you will supply the actual username and password.

Comment: read it from somewhere else (DB or some other file)

Comment: +1 This is a great question and I wish more people would think this way.

Comment: @Ashalynd, which is possibly even less secure.

Comment: …that said, if you're really accessing the site via `http`, the password is being sent in the clear over the network, so [don't kill yourself trying to keep it secret](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17319/is-it-worth-the-effort-to-store-ftp-passwords-encrypted)

Comment: @Jeffrey, you are right, some additional things have to be done, for example store these data in the file which can be read by that script when it runs from server, but not by a random user. Plus encrypt the password and keep the key in yet another place. And if possible use https to communicate with the remote server, because otherwise these things indeed make less sense.

Answer (score 2):

The way Magento handles this, for one example, is by having a global key that is generated at install time. Sensitive data is stored encrypted in the database and transparently decrypted on request using the key that is stored on the filesystem. If an intruder gains access to the database, but not the filesystem, he won't be able (trivially) to get to the sensitive data.

Having the key in a file also makes it a one-stop-shop for quickly invalidating all the sensitive data on the site, if need arises.

Comment: The key point here is that the attacker needs to have gained access to two *distinct* systems to recover the data: the contents of the file and the contents of the database.

Comment: @IMSoP *ish*. If the db gets compromised it's one thing, but if the fs gets compromised the attacker can use the files to get access to the database. But honestly, if you have an untrusted person on your filesystem you're pretty far gone, security wise.

Comment: Well, the idea presumably is that *read-only* access to the source files is not enough (assuming there are also network limits on inbound connections to the DB, etc). Note that the question doesn't refer to databases at all, so from that point of view, it is the database that is being added in this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could set it as a server variable. In Apache, using the `mod_env` module, you should use `httpd.conf` (sometimes called `apache.conf` or `apache2.conf` on some servers). It is also possible to put it in your `.htaccess` file (be 100% sure that it is not accessible from the outside, however!).

```
SetEnv EXAMPLE_SITE_USERNAME myusername
SetEnv EXAMPLE_SITE_PASSWORD s0m3pazw0rd
```

And then in PHP you can access it using `$_SERVER`:

```
$user = $_SERVER['EXAMPLE_SITE_USERNAME'];
$pass = $_SERVER['EXAMPLE_SITE_PASSWORD'];
$data = getdata('http://examplesite.com?options', $user, $pass);
```

Comment: +1 this is a pretty reasonable approach if you can't/don't want something terribly sophisticated.

Comment: The only advantage I can see to this is that it may be slightly trickier to get read access to the config files than to the PHP files, but both should be pretty unlikely. It has the disadvantage of making the data a global variable, making it a little easier for attacks within PHP to recover it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about Apache serving up php source by accident for example if php gets turned off then you could always put the login credentials in a config file above your webroot.

Comment: If the attacker have FTP access to the source code, it has access above the webroot as well.

Comment: This makes at least as much sense as moving it to a DB or config file. There will always be *somewhere* that the attacker could find it, if they happen to compromise the right component.

Comment: If the attacker has ftp access to your server then something has gone terribly wrong.  It's a little misleading to call them an attacker at that point you've lost.

Answer (score -1):

The most secure way is communicating through a Database, or as Technobyte said you can go with another file that is restricted through your .htaccess file

Comment: There's no particular reason to assume that a database is less likely to be compromised than your source code.

Answer (score -2):

This is standard practice. At some point your script will need to know the password, so you can't hash it. PHP files are not generally web visible but you could further protect it with an .htaccess file to deny remote access to the file.

If you are concerned about casual users who have ftp access seeing the file then you could take one additional step and obfuscate the string by encoding it with base64 and decoding it when you need to use it.

Example from php.net:

```
<?php
$str = 'VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==';
echo base64_decode($str);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
"This is an encoded string"
```

Comment: How could that possibly help??  Is an attacker going to not be able to run base64_decode on a string??

Comment: ...how is that safe?  If someone has FTP access, you're screwed, end of story.  Plus, given how ubiquitous base64 encoding/decoding is, that's not really doing anything.

Comment: This is not designed to prevent attack - I did say it would only be useful IF they were concerned about "casual users" not attackers or anyone LOOKING for a password... it isn't safe. There is no "SAFE" once someone has FTP access. This is a measure to OBFUSCATE... as described.